# Firebase crashalytics hang loading - RN

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have RN project which I like to connect it `ErrorBoundry` into `crashalytics`

```
export default class ErrorBoundry extends React.Component<any, IState> {
    state = { hasError: false }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        console.log('crash', { error })
        crashlytics().log(JSON.stringify({ error }))
        return { hasError: true }
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.hasError ? (
            <View style={globalStyles.errorFullScreenContainer}>
                <Text style={globalStyles.errorFullScreenText}>{i18n.t('generic-error')}</Text>
            </View>
        ) : (
            this.props.children
        )
    }
}
```

I did all relevant steps from [docs here](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup), but still dashboard loads (for more than a day after manually throwing few errors and getting into `ErrorBoundry` screen in build env)

[image: this is screenshot]

Relevant package.json

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "12.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "12.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "12.0.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

Notes -

1. `firebase/messaging` working as expected for a while, so app indeed connected to cloud project
2. This also the issue with ios, though accords [docs here](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage), there is no further step after auto `pod install`
3. No errors in the terminal in `install` || `build` parts

Any help will be appreciated, really can't figure what I'm missing

***edit -***
Have also tried `crashlytics().recordError`, same result

Comment: you need to send a crash to firebase. And 
it is disabled in development. https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage#enable-debug-crash-logs

Comment: `for more than a day after manually throwing few errors and getting into ErrorBoundry screen` - In build env

Comment: I mean you are missing a crash / an error. log() is only providing message for next crash.  In case, you might want to call `recordError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people fustrated by that,

It took 5 days, but suddenly dashboard appeared. Hang tight

Now new logs take about 2-3 hour ish

Answer (score 0):

hope you are doing well. Here are the steps I have done to pass through the loading page:

1. Make sure you have correctly installed the firebase packages and added the firebase config file into your project as the document stated: [document](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage)
2. Open the firebase console and go into the crashlytics page (the screenshot you have shown in this question)
3. You need to manually make a crash in your app. **Please call the below function** somewhere inside your app (better assign to a button and click it to trigger)

   ```
   crashlytics().crash()
   ```

---

I think you should have done the step 1 & 2,
so what you have missed should be **just manually crash the app**.
Please try on your side and tell me your result. Cheers!